# Where is System.Windows.Forms assembly

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly, assemblies

I have Visual Studio 2019, and an **empty** .net framework project.
I would like to build a windows forms project by code only (without using
any template).

For this goal I need System.Windows.Forms assembly:

Right click on the project --> Add --> Reference --> COM ---->Where is that assembly?

p.s   There is something which is called System_windows_forms ('-' instead of '.'), and this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add -> Reference -> Assemblies: Framework

`System.Windows.Forms` is part of the .NET Framework and is installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). Visual Studio will find the reference without you having to look for the location. Where exactly the assembly is located is a complicated story, since you are actually referencing a 'Reference Assembly' that is related to the framework version you are targeting, and live under the Visual Studio install path. At runtime, the assembly in the GAC will be used. The GAC is a directory under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET`,

Comment: Additional question: As you write, Windows.Forms is part of the .net Framework (3.5, 4.x,... 4.8) and NOT part of Visual Studio. So.. e.g. a label control to .forms also is part of the framework and can change principally between the framework versions. Is that correct? With .net core this change completely - where exactly the controls are defined/stored in .net core? -> Thanks!

Comment: For .NET Core there is no GAC. The assembly is either in the shared .NET installation your that program loads (under program files under the "dotnet" directory) or might in the directory of the program for self-contained applications. So for .NET core "it depends".

Comment: The only options when right clicking my solution are to add a project reference, a COM reference, and a shared project reference. I see all these guides saying to do Add -> Reference, but that control doesn't exist that I can find.